# Android Scrollview Compressing Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I have created a form that is long and hence, needs to be scrolled vertically. I added a Scrollview to achieve this. However, the form is being compressed into only 75% of the screen after adding the scrollview rather than expanding vertically. I appear to have made some mistake related to layout weight but I am not able to locate it.

It will be great if someone could help me debug it.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sv1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.jaya.myapplication.display_clientdetails">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/white">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:text="@string/edit_client"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deletebutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_delete"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:text="@string/delete_client"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/namelabel_display"
        android:text="@string/name_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/namevalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/doblabel_display"
        android:text="@string/dob_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dobvalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mnumlabel_display"
        android:text="@string/mnum_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mnumvalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emaillabel_display"
        android:text="@string/email_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailvalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/altnumlabel_display"
        android:text="@string/altnum_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/altnumvalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/homeadrlabel_display"
        android:text="@string/homeadr_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/homeadrvalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/offadrlabel_display"
        android:text="@string/offadr_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/offadrvalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noteslabel_display"
        android:text="@string/notes_label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_form"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/notesvalue"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="3"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting height of your Main LinearLayout to match_parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you're using [Weight inside a Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

Keep in mind that the purpose of weight is to distribute real-estate between views inside the `LinearLayout` according to how much space the `LinearLayout` has available.

This way, if `View` A has a `weight` of 1, and `View` B has a `weight` of 2, then `View` A will get 33% of the space inside the `LinearLayout`, and `View` B will get the rest.

The key factor to remember here, is that the whole concept of `weight` hinges on the idea that the `LinearLayout` has a limited amount of real-estate. This changes the moment you put the `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`.

In this pattern, the `LinearLayout` can grow as much as it needs - even beyond the screen limits, and the `ScrollView` handles which portion of it is currently visible.

Since the `LinearLayout` now needs to grow as much as it can, there is no longer any meaning to `weight`, since real-estate is unlimited. It's as if you ask one `View` to take 33% of an unlimited amount of space - what is it supposed to do?

If you're sure you want to work with a scrollable `LinearLayout`, then I would suggest removing the `weight` parameter from the subviews, and telling all the subviews to `wrap_content` on their height (or give them some other height definition in `dp`).

Hope this helps.